# Why does my Windows 7 fresh install report all drivers as being unsigned/untrusted, even if they're from official sources?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ssl, itunes, certificate

I just performed a fresh install of Windows 7 x64 on some modern AMD hardware and I'm having some problems I can't solve.

Firstly I noticed that installer packages for certain programs were refusing to run because the packages were "corrupt" or couldn't be verified. A similar issue affected iTunes which reported that a valid SSL certificate couldn't be found. This turned out to be missing root certificates which weren't in the root certificate store. I imported all of the root certificates from a working copy of Windows 7 on another computer, and this allowed these programs to install.

Now the issues I'm having are:

- Any driver software I install presents a warning "*Windows can't verify publisher of this driver software*" and I have to click "Install anyway" to proceed. This includes software from known publishers including Logitech Gaming Software.
- iTunes is unable to access the iTunes Store and it won't let me sign in. There are no error messages but I suspect it must be related to these SSL/certificate issues.

**Things I've tried:**

- As mentioned, I imported all root certificates from a working computer
- I've made sure that the group policy at `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Internet Communications Management\Internet Communication Settings\Turn off automatic root certificates update` is not enabled.

Web browsing etc. is totally unaffected and works fine.

Comment: Is your clock set to current date and time?

Comment: This could only be caused by a certificate store problem, specifically you have not installed a required update, that allows the current certificates to be trusted.  Has this system installed ALL Windows 7 updates, specifically those updates, that install the newest certificates?

Comment: Moab Yes it is. @Ramhound I believe it does but I will double check that. I will also try importing all certificates from another W7 PC across all certificate stores. Thanks!

Comment: @WackGet - That operator won't work without the update that supports those certificates.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have any idea which updates, specifically? The list of installed updates is quite comprehensive but I can double check. I wasn't able to find a list by just searching for things like "SSL certificate Windows updates".

Comment: @WackGet - Every update released after June 2017.  Basically every single released update.